# Android can't open .xls file

Tags: android, excel

In my app i've got some data which I'd like to display into an Excel sheet.

Some days ago I've already managed to build the file .xls.

I've also been able to sent it by email whith this code:

```
 FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), (main.getNomeAzienda() + "" + getDate(System.currentTimeMillis(), "dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm")) + ".xls");
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                workbook.write(fos);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            i.setType("message/rfc822");
                            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()});
                            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), "com.example.authority.fileprovider", file));
                            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Raccolto globale aSista");
                            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "In allegato il File Excel con i dati filtrati.");
                            try {
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Seleziona il Client di posta che vuoi utilizzare..."));
                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                                Snackbar.make(main.getFab(), "Non ci sono client di posta disponibili installati sul dispositivo.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                }
                Snackbar.make(main.getFab(), "Foglio Excel generato.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Sorry if some parts of the code are in italian.

Anyway, now I'd like to display the excel file directly on the phone.

I downloaded some apps which should be able to display .xls file. Like [Excel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.excel), [this one from google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.sheets) and [polaris office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infraware.office.link).

With this code i call the intent which ask the user to choose one of those app and open the file:

```
   Uri path = Uri.fromFile(finalFile);
                            Intent excelIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            excelIntent.setDataAndType(path , "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                            excelIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            try {
                                startActivity(excelIntent);
                            }
                            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                Snackbar.make(main.getFab(),"Impossibile aprire il file su questo dispositivo",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
```

I've faced some problems related to the name of the file, which should't include some special characters. Then i finally been able to start opening the file but now i've got a problem.

Excel tells me "is not possible to open the file, an error has occurred".

Google docs the same.

Polaris doesn't display errors but it show an empty file.

Comment: Try using `FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), "com.example.authority.fileprovider", finalFile)` in your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, and replace your current `setFlags()` with  `excelIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` as part of configuring `excelIntent`.

Comment: Wow it's working. thanks!  If you want to write it as an aswer I'll mark it as right one ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is in `getFilesDir()`. That is part of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), and third-party apps do not have access to your portion of internal storage.

Since you already have `FileProvider` set up, use the `FileProvider` `Uri`, and use `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to give temporary read access to the other app.